# How do mutations of viruses lead to drug resistance?

Tags: genetics, microbiology, molecular-genetics, virology

For instance, after starting [zidovudine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/26324274) monotherapy against HIV, resistance develops against the drug because of a point mutation in the RNA transcriptase enzyme to which the drug binds.

So how does the virus ‘know’ to mutate this particular enzyme?

Comment: @David After your edits, the answers no longer make sense. Yes, the question was based on a misunderstanding, but the answers explain why that understanding was wrong.

Comment: @Barmar, I've restored the original title question.  I agree the changed title had reduced the value of the answers for little benefit.

Comment: @mgkrebbs — I think we can improve the question by improving rather than restoring a bad title. I have had another go. The essence of the misapprehension remains, but it is no longer expresses it as an assertion, which I have reintroduced in the body of the question.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think so, because a title is not a question, and the last sentence of the question still encompasses the misapprehension. However, I have had another go at the title and altered the last sentence to explicitly include the "know" that appears in the accepted answer.

Comment: Coming in from outside, after having visited this question once before, the new title makes the answers make no sense.

Comment: @probably_someone I have edited the title to capture the revised title without destroying the context of the top answers.

Comment: @James I regard that as unnecessary (the last sentence in the question includes "know") and retrograde. By retaining the original title you are propagating the non-scientific thinking of a question which should have been closed for the lack of research.

Comment: @David I appreciate your point and agree completely that we should not encourage the idea of sentient evolution (or whatever you want to call it). However, when asking a question, it is more helpful if the title is a question rather than a topic/chapter title. What do you think of this one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is molecular evolution and is completely undirected.
Mutations happen all the time, most of them disappear without anyone noticing, since they have no evolutionary advantage to permeate.

This is different when you treat the cells and put them under an evolutionary pressure. Under this conditions, mutations which affect the mechanism of the drug (as here with a single point of binding) pose a great advantage for survival and with subsequent generations all carrying this mutation. This mechanism is simply a statistical one as the numbers of viruses produced in the infection is really large. It is not a matter **if** such a mutation occurs, only when.

Such a selection of specific clones is seen in other diseases too, leaving to the deactivation of the drug or the activation of different signal pathways, avoiding the one which has been targeted.

If you want to read further on viruses and mutation rates/mutations, take one of the following articles.

References:

1. [Mutation—The Engine of Evolution: Studying Mutation and Its Role in
   the Evolution of Bacteria](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4563715/)
2. [Antiviral drug resistance as an adaptive process](https://academic.oup.com/ve/article/2/1/vew014/1753530)
3. [Mechanisms of viral mutation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5075021/)
4. [Why are RNA virus mutation rates so damn high?](https://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.3000003)

Answer (score 54):

It doesn't. Viruses don't "know" anything. [Mutations occur at random. Most of them don't do anything, or have a slight negative effect on the ability of the virus to infect and reproduce](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/biology-of-viruses/virus-biology/a/evolution-of-viruses). However, there are billions and billions of viruses. Once in a while a random mutation will offer a significant advantage like immunity to an anti-viral drug. The viruses that have that beneficial mutation will then massively out-reproduce the viruses that don't have it. Eventually the population of viruses will consist mostly of individual viruses that have that mutation.

Comment: Are you suggesting every mutation ever happened is just an accident?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's just that there are billions and billions of them, so sometimes something useful crops up.

Comment: @user73023 The same is true for all the mutations in every species of bacteria, plant, animal, etc.

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, not all mutations are accidents. GMOs were created by humans.

Comment: @Jagoe: Well, humans are an accident :-)  And from a strictly linguistic point of view, the changes made to GMOs are not mutations.

Comment: @Jagoe Even mutations involved in creating GMOs are random. You try to target a specific piece of DNA, but what will you actually modify is based on chance. Same like throwing the ball on target. You are trying to hit the centre, but you might go off. Most GM process involve stage where you try to look at the thing you created and verify that the change occured at the place you wanted and that there are no side effects.

Comment: @Jagoe here's one (crude) way how some  GMOs were developed through random mutations - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_gardening

Comment: @jamesqf Not really, if you look at the big picture. Genes are replicators that create vessels for themselves to spread. As part of those vessels, they managed to build brains, which themselves are capable of supporting their own replicators - cultural information, memes. Those memes hijacked the "plans" of the genes (oops!), just what happened probably a few times before (any parasite in the broad sense does the same thing). When you look at humanity as a whole, much of our progress is through the same mutation-and-selection process, just _ridiculously_ faster than genes could ever do.

Comment: @Jagoe Except that GMOs have been created by nature over and over again. We just adopted the same mechanism, and tweaked it for our own purposes. Both selective breeding and "modern" genetic manipulation are things that happen in nature all the time. And it's not like humans are all that special; we've developed thanks to natural selection, just like every living thing on this planet. Retroviruses change genomes of other organisms (including ours) too; bacteria share plasmids; many plants routinely hybridize like crazy (wheat and citrus fruits are probably the most visible crazy hybrids :)).

Comment: Billions sound like greatly underestimated when this site claims there are hundred million virus particles in a single cough drop https://www.livescience.com/3686-gross-science-cough-sneeze.html  They wouldn't evolve nearly as fast if there were just billions.

Comment: The genetic changes in GMOs have been facilitated or caused by humans, hence they are not random in the sense that someone intended those changes to happen. And GMOs are in fact, artificially-induced mutants. By definition, there are no natural GMOs.

Comment: @jamesqf Not all humans are accidents. Many of us are born because our parents wanted to. Those resulting from unintended pregnancies are accidents in the sense of their parents not expecting them, not because they are something unfortunate.

Comment: @Luaan Humans have also developed thanks to genetic drift, gene flow and selective mating. Natural selection is not the only process in evolution.

Comment: @Jagoe Well, of course. When we talk about natural selection being important, we're talking about adaptive evolution, which is the buildup of complex systems piece by piece. Things like tails becoming longer can easily be due to genetic drift and such. But it still fits the general pattern - genes building machines to spread genes, and those machines not always doing what's best for the spreading of genes. I'm not sure what part of what I'm saying you're disagreeing with. What makes us human still developed through natural selection, even though it's not the only effect at play.

Comment: @Luaan I thought that you were using natural selection and evolution interchangeably.

Comment: @Colombo Yes and no. The problem with CRISPR-Cas9 is not that it misses its target, but that it introduces unintended changes in the same area in addition. It's certainly not the same kind of random as in atomic gardening.

Comment: @Jagoe: You completely misunderstood my comment.  I meant that human beings AS A SPECIES are an accident.  As for individual children... Well, the parents may have intended to produce A child, but until genetic engineering progresses a lot further, the particular child they get is still an accident.

Answer (score 7):

#### Summary: They Don't.

Long explanation:

Mutations happen at random. A series of factors can lead to the perceived notion that the mutation was intentional.

1. The mutation can be harmful, beneficial, or neutral.

   1. **Harmful:** We don't see the harmful mutations as these individuals don't proliferate. The mutant individual just dies off without passing their genetic material forward, or they die out after just a few generations.
   2. **Beneficial:** To the virus' viewpoint, of course. The mutants gain a competitive advantage over the other strains, and proliferate. This advantage may be noticed (e.g., as in the case of developing drug resistance).
   3. **Neutral:** Most of the time, the mutation won't affect the individual's performance. Due to the mechanism of [codon degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codon_degeneracy), changes in one base in the DNA code may not even cause a structural change to the codon's amino acid equivalent.
2. Most viruses are not successful in reproducing. Those that are make millions of copies of themselves. One successful mutant has the potential of creating a whole new strain.
3. Viruses too are subject to selective forces. In the case of drug resistance, the successful resistant mutant won't have to compete with the other strains as the drug already eliminated them.
4. Drug resistance is not immunity. However, a resistant strain can very well mutate again to develop a stronger resistance.

We only observe the final effect (a new virus strain that seems to be engineered) but not the intermediate steps. There was a lot of (random) intermediate and unsuccessful mutations in between.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is off topic, but as a developer, my eyes were opened when I learned genetic algorithms. While the mathematics are tangential to actual biology, I think it illustrates the mechanism of an environmentally directed evolution of random mutations. An example I have is here:
https://github.com/Jarrod1937/genetic-algo-example/blob/master/ga/Form1.cs

The mutations are random, but the fitness function defines when the mutation is beneficial. In the case of a virus, the virus successfully propagating is the fitness function, and thus those of a higher fitness are more likely to propagate more, thus you see the increasing adaption against things that prevent propagation. However, this isn't the virus knowing where or how to adapt, rather, it is a case of sample bias. Your sample of viruses are the ones that survived and propagated, you don't see all of the failures that came before.

Comment: Hi Jarrod - this is the same way biology works, as described in the existing answers by Charles, Chris, and Mindwin. The mutations are random; what makes certain mutations increase their prevalence in the population is selection (effectively, this is the fitness function), plus other random components like genetic drift (which has most effect for mutations that have no or a small survival cost or benefit). Genetic algorithms sometimes cheat a bit, though, and have non-random mutations or other algorithmic tricks in selection and 'mating' that are not accessible to biology.